# How to get Android Device Back key event in Aspectj

Tags: android, aop, aspectj

I want an event for android device back in aspectj. If i override onBackPressed() in code and same i use in aspectj like "pointcut onBackPressed() : execution(* onBackPressed());" i am getting the event for back. But most of the screen doesn't requrired to handle device back key, in that case will not override onBackPressed(). And in such case i am not getting any event for device back key.
Is there any event present in aspectj for handling android device back key?

Comment: its obvious that if you dont override `onBackPressed()` you will not get the event on that screen and it will function normally.. Be a lil more clear while asking the question.

Comment: Thanks aditya. I want to know that how to get device back key event in aspectj (AOP). I am generating robotium script based on the user events, i am able to get events like onClick().. but not getting any event for device Back key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to intercept an `execution` joinpoint in a 3rd party library, you have three options:

- Recompile the library from source (if available) and weave your aspect into it.
- Perform binary weaving on the class files in the JAR, creating newly woven versions, then re-package the JAR and replace the original.
- Use LTW and weave the library's classes during class-loading.

Either way, you need to be in control of the code you want to weave into. Otherwise the only fall-back is to use a `call` pointcut so as to weave the callers instead of the callee. But this again will only work for calls made by code under your control, not for calls made from 3rd party code, e.g. from inside the library.

Answer (score 0):

I still dont know if i got you right..
but see if this can help you.. i have no experience in AOP

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        //Back key event suppose to handled here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Hi Aditya, its related to AOP. I understand there are two way to handle the device back event like override onBackPressed() or onKeyDown(). Generally developer will not handle the back action untill its required. But i want this back action in ASPECTJ if user press the device back key, it doesn't matter if developer has handled back event or not in android code.